# How to know the ID of an auto incremented column in a "one to many" database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I have a database consists of 2 tables with "one to many" relationship

```
the first table:

CREATE TABLE data (
  personid int not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  phone int ,
  primary key (personid)
)
```

The second table:

```
CREATE TABLE links (
  linkid int not null auto_increment,
  link varchar(255),
  personid int,
  primary key (linkid),
  foreign key (personid)
    references data(personid)

)
```

I insert records to the first table and each new record gets a new ID , Then enter links to this ID , I want to know how to know the ID of the person to insert the links to him via php/sql

Comment: Get the last inserted id after insertion in first table and then use that id into second table

Answer (score 2):

use `Mysqli` or `PDO` -

With PDO:

`$personid = $pdo->lastInsertId();`

With Mysqli:

`$personid = $mysqli->insert_id;`

And then again Insert data `links` table data using above `$personid`.

You have to start using `Mysqli` or `PDO` to write the code in `PHP`.

Stay with standards :)

Comment: what if id already exist and I want to know this id to add more links to this id ?

Comment: Danny - if the ID already exists from a previous insert, you'll need to run a separate SELECT query to find it. If you only want to know the most recently inserted ID for inserting into the second table, then this method will work.